# Sametime Plugin Development Using Eclipse 3.5 and ST 7.5

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, sametime

I have been trying to setup a Dev environment for Sametime Plugin Development for a week now but I am facing issues in one form or the other. The issues that I am facing are

1. After setting up the Env, the extension point schemas are missing and i am getting only the word "Generic" instead of the actual extension.
2. The above issue made me edit Plugin.xml manually and added the instructions given in the Extending Sametime Redbook. The plugin itself is not loading let alone my customizations.

I am in quandry as to how to proceed from here. I am stuck, i have tried download different versions of eclipse from 3.2 to 3.5 and none of them have worked.

I would appreciate if someone could help me on this, its really frustrating :(

Comment: eclipse3.2 should be the official recommended version to have here. You did follow all the steps of http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG247346/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm ?

Comment: yeap I followed the exact same steps that was given in the redbook. The whole setup is working but for some reason the Eclipse Extension points are not available when i do a right click. Not sure why because  i specified the source code locations also. Right now I am manually editing the Plugin.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Just to update if anyone is trying to find a solution to the "Generic" issue mentioned above. You need to change the target platform to Eclipse. While running the client, you need to change it back to sametime.

Answer (score 0):

The extension point schemas are only part of source builds of eclipse.
The [Eclipse RCP](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR1/eclipse-rcp-galileo-SR1-win32.zip) contains the source code of Eclipse and for this reason also the extension point schemas. This version of Eclipse is used for developing rich client applications based on Eclipse and for developing Eclipse plugins.